# GetView in adapter never gets executed

Tags: android, user-interface, android-arrayadapter

I have a following code in my custom adapter. I'm trying to set text in CheckedTextView, but it doesn't work. When I'm using debugger I can see getView and getCount is never called. What's wrong?

```
public class AccessPoint extends ArrayAdapter {

    private List<String> name  = new ArrayList<String>();

    public AccessPoint(Context context, int textViewResourceId, List<String> objects) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
        this.name.addAll(objects);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return name.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return name.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          CheckedTextView textView = (CheckedTextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text);
          textView.setText(name.get(position));
        return convertView;
    }

}
```

This is how I add adapter to listview:

```
accessPoints.add(new AccessPoint(getBaseContext(), 2131361936, objects));

        accessPointsListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<AccessPoint>(this, layout.access_point, accessPoints));
```

And my xml file, which resides in listview:

```
<CheckedTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
android:checkMark="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorSingle"
android:drawablePadding="8dp"
android:drawableLeft="@drawable/image1"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:paddingLeft="2dip"
android:id="@+id/text"
android:paddingRight="2dip"
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
```

Comment: the only possibility I see here is that getCount() returns 0, and what do you mean by "Textviews text never changes", are they in the listview ?? can you elaborate on that

Comment: what is textViewResourceId?

Comment: Just to be sure: Did you add the adapter to the listview?

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have edited my question. When I use debugger I can see that getCount() is also never called.

Comment: You're creating an `ArrayAdapter` that contains an array of `AccessPoint` adapter objects. Renaming `AccessPoint` to `AccessPointAdapter` might make things a bit clearer.